# How to direct Ubuntu to use USB connection for Internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, easytether

I posted yesterday regarding [how to configure easytether](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16168/how-to-install-tethering-s-w-easytether) on Ubuntu. I followed the steps and everything looks good from the terminal. But I am not able to connect to the Internet. Currently I am connected to a Wireless network, I tried disconnecting to it, in hope to connect to Internet using my phone but with no help. How do I make my notebook use my cell phone's connection. I have attached the snapshot from the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting up your phone in the usual way? (That is, did it show up in network-manager after you've plugged it in for the first time?) If so, have you encountered any specific errors there?

Comment: What kind of phone is this and what version of Android do you have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use any DataCards on Ubuntu for Internet

`sudo apt-get install wvdial`

- run these:
- `lsusb`
- `modprobe`
- `wvdial`
- `modprobe usbserial vendor =0x0eab product =0×9357`
  (check the output of `lsusb` for it)
- open editor for the file `/etc/wvdial.conf` (you can run the command `gksu gedit /etc/wvdial.conf` in a terminal) and enter the following lines and save:

> [Dialer Defaults]
>
> ```
> Init1 = ATZ
>
> Init2 = ATE0V1
>
> Modem Type = Analog Modem
>
> Baud = 115200
>
> New PPPD = yes
>
> Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
>
> ISDN = 0
>
> Stupid Mode = 1
>
> Phone = #777 // this is for dialing e.g for reliance
>
> Password =
>
> Username =
> ```

To avoid `modprobe` everytime system boots write a simple script i.e on a simple text file and save it with the name `modprobe-1.sh` , make it executable by running `chmod +x modprobe-s.sh` and save this file in `/usr/bin` or in `/bin` after that just run `modeprobe-1` ( it will work like custom command).

> #! /bin/bash
>
> echo pwd | sudo -S modprobe usbserial vendor =0x0eab product =0×9357
>
> echo pwd | sudo -S wvdial

(where pwd is your sudo password)

Answer (score 0):

I checked [this link](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2009/12/how-to-tether-your-verizon-droid-as.html) and [this one](http://androidforums.com/evo-4g-tips-tricks/146871-easy-tether-ubuntu-10-04-a.html#post1369248), a bit shorter and using easytether. it seems that everything you are doing is correct.  Have you actually done what you need to do on your phone?  i.e. gone into wireless settings and allow share network, etc.?  You might need to look up if there is an extra setting with your model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  this we have implemented with USB based Data Card

on ubuntu as well as on RHEL, Are you looking for internet sharing then you have to

do use iptables and search for ip masquerading and internet sharing

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you have an Android phone that has version 2.2(i think) or Android 2.3, there should be an option under Wireless & Networks..there should be a an option of tethering through USB. I hope that helps you.